# Calling DLL function in AutoIt, DLLStruct has no data

Tags: c++, autoit, cen-xfs

I am new here and I will try to explain my best.
I am writing some Info tool that needs to return some data on specific hardware ATM related, so I have its API and it's  documentation is totally confusing to code in VB6 C++ 
so  I need to call specific dll function that original code in c++ was like this:

```
typedef struct _wfsversion
{
    WORD            wVersion;
    WORD            wLowVersion;
    WORD            wHighVersion;
    CHAR            szDescription[WFSDDESCRIPTION_LEN+1];
    CHAR            szSystemStatus[WFSDSYSSTATUS_LEN+1];
} WFSVERSION, * LPWFSVERSION;

//and  Function calls APi and expect some  response.

BOOL Wfs_StartUp(void)
{
    WFSVERSION WfsVersion;
    return (WFSStartUp(RECOGNISED_VERSIONS, &WfsVersion) == WFS_SUCCESS);

#define RECOGNISED_VERSIONS 0X00030203
```

---

In AutoIt I did the following:

```
#include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <Constants.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
Global Const  $hXFSDLL = DllOpen ( "C:\Coding\infotool\msxfs.dll")
Global Const $RECOGNISED_VERSIONS = "0X00030203"
Global Const $lpWFSVersion = "word wVersion;word wLowVersion;word wHighVersion;char szDescription[WFSDDESCRIPTION_LEN+1];char szSystemStatus[WFSSYSSTATUS_LEN+1]"
$structLPWFSVERSION = DllStructCreate($lpWFSVersion)
DllCall($hXFSDLL,"BOOL","WFSStartUp","dword",$RECOGNISED_VERSIONS, "struct", DllStructGetPtr($structLPWFSVERSION))
ConsoleWrite("wVersion = "&DllstructGetData($structLPWFSVERSION,"wVersion"))
ConsoleWrite(@CRLF)
ConsoleWrite("wLowVersion = "&DllstructGetData($structLPWFSVERSION,"wLowVersion"))
ConsoleWrite(@CRLF)
ConsoleWrite("wHighVersion = "&DllstructGetData($structLPWFSVERSION,"wHighVersion"))
ConsoleWrite(@CRLF)
ConsoleWrite("szDescription = "&DllstructGetData($structLPWFSVERSION,"szDescription"))
ConsoleWrite(@CRLF)
ConsoleWrite("szSystemStatus = "&DllstructGetData($structLPWFSVERSION,"szSystemStatus"))
ConsoleWrite(@CRLF)
```

and as response I get no data:

```
wVersion = 0
wLowVersion = 0
wHighVersion = 0
szDescription = 0
szSystemStatus = 0
```

so I wonder what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the value for WFSDDESCRIPTION_LEN and WFSSYSSTATUS_LEN comes from? Try to replace those 2 constants with the appropriate integer value and add 1, then put the temporary integer into the lpWFSVersion string.

Comment: Exactly that was error, I changed  with 256+1 as stated in xfsapi.h :(

Answer (score 1):

Besides what mrt commented I think your function description is wrong.
`WFSStartUp` wants **struct pointer** not a **struct** so the type should be `struct*` not `struct`.

```
Local $ret = DllCall($hXFSDLL, "LONG:cdecl", "WFSStartUp", "dword", $RECOGNISED_VERSIONS, "struct*", DllStructGetPtr($structLPWFSVERSION))
```

EDIT:
I changed the above signature to reflect the fact that `msxfs.dll` is NOT using stdcall calling convention but `cdecl` as this is what AutoIt documentation for `DllCall` say about calling conventions:

> By default, AutoIt uses the 'stdcall' calling method. To use the 'cdecl' method place ':cdecl' after the return type.

The `DllCall` documentation I quoted can be found here:
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/DllCall.htm

Comment: It works with: struct* or ptr,I get Values from Console Write
Problem is now that I cant verify return code, it is NULL, I tried Boolean , bool, integer and none returns anything when I do it like this:
`$ret=DllCall($hXFSDLL,"BOOL","WFSStartUp","dword",$RECOGNISED_VERSIONS, "struct", DllStructGetPtr($structLPWFSVERSION))
ConsoleWrite("wVersion = "&DllstructGetData($structLPWFSVERSION,"wVersion"))`
I changed values for WFSDESCRIPTION and WFSSYSSTATUS
WFSstarup should return numbervalue:
WFS_SUCCESS (0)
WFS_ERR_ALREADY_STARTED (-1)
WFS_ERR_API_VER_TOO_HIGH (-2)
WFS_ERR_API_VER_TOO_LOW (-3)